# unable to encode url in mysql php insert

Tags: php, mysql, urlencode

I am trying to insert a url to mysql(through php) column but unable to do it.
I am getting the following error

> `Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fclient%2Fsave_file.php%3Ffilename%3D9 WHERE queryid='29'' at line 1`

The code snippet :

```
 $_POST['url1']="//localhost/client/save_file.php?filename=9";
 $_POST['query_id']=29; 


        $var=$_POST['url1'];
        $query_id=$_POST['query_id'];

   //     echo    "$var";
        $var=rawurlencode($var);
        //echo  "$var";
        $sql1 = "UPDATE query_audio SET query_content=$var WHERE queryid='".$query_id."' ";
          if (!mysql_query($sql1)) {
             die('Error: ' . mysql_error($connection));              
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to defend against [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) You need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, not `urlencode()`.

Plus, you forgot to quote your `$var` variable, so your query is litterally:

```
... SET query_content=http:%2F%2Fetc...
```

Without quotes around that url, mysql is free to interpret the `http:` portion as an (invalid) field name.

Try

```
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url1']);
$query_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POSt['query_id']);

$sql = "UDPATE ... SET query_content='$var' WHERE queryid='$query_id';";
                                     ^----^-- note these quotes.
```